# please show that $\hat\mu_i\sim N(\mu_i,\frac {\sigma^2}{n_i})$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Statistical model for *Complete Randomized design*

$y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$

where, $i$ denotes treatment and $j$ denotes observation.

$i=1,2,...,k\quad and \quad j=1,2,..., n_i$

$y_{ij}$ be a random variable that represents the response obtained on the $jth$
observation of the  $ith$ treatment.

$\mu$ is the overall mean of the response $y_{ij}$

$\tau_i$ is the effect on the response of $ith$ treatment.

$\mu_i = \mu + \tau_i$

here $\mu_i$ denotes the *true response*  of the $ith$ treatment.

and $\epsilon_{ij}$ is the random error term represent the sources of nuisance variation that is, variation due to factors other than treatments.

the assuption is $\epsilon_{ij}\sim^{iid} N(0,\sigma^2)$

so  $y_{ij}\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$

now it is written on the book that $\hat\mu_i\sim N(\mu_i,\frac {\sigma^2}{n_i})$
but i couldn't calculate that how $\hat\mu_i$ is normally distributed as mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\frac {\sigma^2}{n_i}$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$ instead?

Comment: yes . it will be $y_{ij}\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$

Comment: i am trying to proceed in MGF technique

Comment: But isn't $\hat{\mu}_i=\frac1{n_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} y_{ij}$?

Comment: yes it is.and i know from $\hat\mu_i=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n_i y_{ij} {n_i}}$=$\hat\mu_i=\bar y_{i.}$  and from here it can be written since $y_{ij}\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$ so its mean $\bar y_{i.}\sim N(\mu_i,\frac{\sigma^2}{n_i})$ .  But i want to go from the model that since $y_{ij}=\mu_i+\epsilon_{ij}$ and so MGF of $\mu_i$ that is $M_{\mu_i}(t)=M_{y_{ij}}(t) \times M_{\epsilon_{ij}}(-t)$

Comment: First of all, I don't understand why you want to do that. Second of all, you're trying to find the MGF of $\mu_i$ which is just a constant (since $\mu$ and $\tau_i$ are constants, right?). Shouldn't you instead find the MGF of $\hat{\mu}_i$?

Comment: How to find the MGF of $\hat\mu_i$ ?

Comment: Use [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Sum_of_independent_random_variables).